# Finding the weakest precondition and invariant of while loop

Tags: loop-invariants, program-correctness

I am trying to find the weakest precondition and invariant of this while loop. I have read and am trying to understand the concept of calculating preconditions based on postconditions. I was wondering if someone could explain it to me.

```
while i < j do 
    i = i + 1;
    j = j - 1;
end 

{i = j or i = j + 1}
```

Comment: Loop invariant here is i<j., As you can clearly see.

Comment: @Seeker I doubt that $i<J$ is strong enough as a loop invariant to  reach the desired post-condition.

Comment: @Martin Don't you think Compliment of what inside {} is loop invariant here? Right?

Comment: @Seeker I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @martin-berger Just for everyone's information, the solution manual states that the loop invariant strong enough to prove the correctness of the loop is: i <= j +1. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Johnny Hmmm, try this with i = 2 and j = 0 ...

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/70363/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/42264743/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.